Как можно остановить работу цикла при помощи символа?
я хочу , чтобы в моем цикле при вводе условно точки цикл останавливал работу. Тему символы понимаю плохо , поэтому мне нужно понять, как это сделать. Вот часть кода
for(;;){
    printf("\nВведите два числа для сравнения: ") ;
    scanf("%f %f, &c, &d);
    printf("\nИтог\n) ;
    printf("%.2f %c %.2f\n", c, math(c, d), d);

math - это функция, которую я в своём коде до этого описал. Как мне прервать работу цикла при помощи символа "."?

Для начала закройте кавычки в scanf("%f %f, &c, &d);. А потом сформулируйте точнее, что значит — прервать при помощи точки? Если вы хотите сказать, что при вводе точки вместо всех этих чисел... — то считывайте строку, и если это не точка, то тогда уже разбирайте ее.

@Harry я написал после scanf if (char(c) == '.'){
break;
}, но у меня после введения точки цикл начинается бесконечно воспроизводиться без дальнейшего вмешательства. Если я вместо точки выберу к примеру "-", то он просто выведет ноль вместо него и продолжит работу

А разве у вас c — символ? Это же число типа float...

@Harry окей, а как мне превратить его в символ?

Повторю еще раз и медленно, как для депутата :) : "считывайте строку, и если это не точка, то тогда уже разбирайте ее"

@Harry, короче, я добавил s = getch(), где s конечно типа char, потом добавил условие if (s=='.') break; И все заработало. Чуть-чуть не так, как я хотел, но все же спасибо, дошло наконец

@Harry а не, вру. Не break, а exit(0);

Что-то такое?
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    for(double c,d;;){
        printf("Введите два числа для сравнения, . для выхода: ") ;
        char buf[128];
        fgets(buf,128,stdin);
        if (buf[0] == '.') break;
        if (2 != sscanf(buf,"%lf %lf", &c, &d))
        {
            printf("Неверный ввод!\n") ;
        }
        else printf("%.2f %c %.2f\n", c, '?', d);
    }
}


ну можно и так, да, спасибо
